# Web API run VB6 COM components in STA mode

Tags: com, vb6, asp.net-web-api

Masters,

I've few past developed VB6 components that are heavily used in our most of the applications

Now, we want to consume same components for newly developing Web API project.

But, as per this post ,
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications

We found strike on Asp.net Web API it might due to we don't have any page in Web API project.

Please tell me correct workaround achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggesting looking into the StaTaskScheduler http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx